# Cisco ASR1006 ESP40 high CPU utilization

Tags: cisco, cisco-nx-os, cpu, asr

We have `ASR1006` with `ASR1000-ESP40` and it seems strange on our SNMP monitoring its showing Max CPU utilization 70% and avg 35% but when i check on command line numbers are totally different, what is the best command to check CPU utilization on Cisco which give correct info.

We are pumping 4Gbps on this router and running BGP with bunch of ACL and netflow.

I want to see who is eating most CPU (i believe it must be ACL but just want to see how much?)

```
ASR1k#sh processes cpu sorted | ex 0.00
CPU utilization for five seconds: 1%/0%; one minute: 0%; five minutes: 0%
 PID Runtime(ms)     Invoked      uSecs   5Sec   1Min   5Min TTY Process
   9    25600016     5332884       4800  0.39%  0.09%  0.06%   0 Check heaps
  15     7546146   212063155         35  0.15%  0.02%  0.01%   0 ARP Input
  68    15299310   289732737         52  0.07%  0.03%  0.02%   0 IOSD ipc task
```

## Update

```
ASR1k#show processes cpu history




                                         11111
  100
   90
   80
   70
   60
   50
   40
   30
   20
   10
     0....5....1....1....2....2....3....3....4....4....5....5....6
               0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0
               CPU% per second (last 60 seconds)





      2 111111 11111115111111 11 1  11111  11 1 1 1111 11111  111
  100
   90
   80
   70
   60
   50
   40
   30
   20
   10                 *
     0....5....1....1....2....2....3....3....4....4....5....5....6
               0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0
               CPU% per minute (last 60 minutes)
              * = maximum CPU%   # = average CPU%





      555665656555555656566655564565555565456565665555566666666556556555656565
  100
   90
   80
   70
   60
   50
   40
   30
   20
   10 ************************** ********* *********************************
     0....5....1....1....2....2....3....3....4....4....5....5....6....6....7..
               0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0
                   CPU% per hour (last 72 hours)
                  * = maximum CPU%   # = average CPU%
```

control-processor output

```
ASR1k#show platform software status control-processor brief
Load Average
 Slot  Status  1-Min  5-Min 15-Min
  RP0 Healthy   0.00   0.00   0.00
  RP1 Healthy   0.06   0.05   0.00
 ESP0 Healthy   0.00   0.00   0.00
 ESP1 Healthy   0.00   0.01   0.00
 SIP0 Healthy   0.00   0.00   0.00
 SIP1 Healthy   0.00   0.00   0.00

Memory (kB)
 Slot  Status    Total     Used (Pct)     Free (Pct) Committed (Pct)
  RP0 Healthy 16342672  3269760 (20%) 13072912 (80%)  11172684 (68%)
  RP1 Healthy 16342672  3191624 (20%) 13151048 (80%)  11164012 (68%)
 ESP0 Healthy  8097460  1046744 (13%)  7050716 (87%)    757672 ( 9%)
 ESP1 Healthy  8097460  1036996 (13%)  7060464 (87%)    755624 ( 9%)
 SIP0 Healthy   969060   344264 (36%)   624796 (64%)    435940 (45%)
 SIP1 Healthy   969060   343832 (35%)   625228 (65%)    435556 (45%)

CPU Utilization
 Slot  CPU   User System   Nice   Idle    IRQ   SIRQ IOwait
  RP0    0   0.80   0.60   0.00  98.49   0.00   0.10   0.00
         1   0.10   0.00   0.00  99.90   0.00   0.00   0.00
  RP1    0   0.50   0.40   0.00  99.10   0.00   0.00   0.00
         1   0.00   0.00   0.00 100.00   0.00   0.00   0.00
 ESP0    0   0.70   8.90   0.00  90.40   0.00   0.00   0.00
         1   0.00   0.10   0.00  99.90   0.00   0.00   0.00
 ESP1    0   1.00   7.20   0.00  91.80   0.00   0.00   0.00
         1   0.19   0.29   0.00  99.50   0.00   0.00   0.00
 SIP0    0   1.40   1.00   0.00  97.60   0.00   0.00   0.00
 SIP1    0   1.30   0.60   0.00  98.00   0.00   0.10   0.00
```

## Updated - 2

```
ASR1k#show platform hardware qfp active datapath utilization summary
  CPP 0:                     5 secs        1 min        5 min       60 min
Input:     Total (pps)      4437420      4442010      4409031      4511954
                 (bps)   5177030592   5174027696   5125677032   5227078152
Output:    Total (pps)      4439532      4444149      4411183      4514112
                 (bps)   5197754704   5194927560   5146659024   5248022568
Processing: Load (pct)           38           38           38           39
```

On monitoring graph (why command line doesn't showing what graph showing)

[image]

Different view of CPU utilization

[image]

Comment: What does the `show processes cpu history` command look like?

Comment: I have updated question.

Comment: what is `qfp F0/0` in graph? and what it does?  i found this ` Cisco QuantumFlow Processor (Cisco QFP)` Am i in danger if it touch 100%?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, but I don't think your graph is the CPU utilization. It may be some I/O graph. Based on the `show processes cpu history` command, your CPU utilization is fine for the last 72 hours.

Comment: I have updated my question with new graph, it does has `CPU 0/0` and `CPU 1/0` I think that is main CPU and QFP is something else, or i should talk to Cisco.

Comment: Look at _[Cisco ASR 1000 Series Aggregation Services Routers: QoS Architecture and Solutions](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/asr-1002-router/solution_overview_c22-449961.html)_.

Comment: What are the exact OIDs you're graphing?

Comment: @Satish The Cisco QuantumFlow Processor (Cisco QFP) shows the utilization of your ASR1000-ESP40. It could be because the ESP module has reached it's capability. Use the command `show platform hardware qfp active datapath utilization summary` to check the utilization of the ESP.

Comment: @Cown i have updated question which output you requested, so you think my ESP is underload but anyway i can see who is using CPU because we have 10G link and only 4G in used. But yes we are using `ACL` so do you think its ACL ?

Comment: @Satish i don't think you need to upgrade yet, but as the output shows and as you've written yourself, the ESP is 40% utilized. Normally i would upgrade around 60% or 50% if the setup is redundant. It has nothing to do with ACL, it's pure packet processing by the ESP.

Comment: What do you mean upgrade? If you see we are touching 70% sometime. This is 40G ESP and we are pumping 4G traffic so what is the use of this device?